# Word for collection of musical artists?

Tags: nouns

If one calls a group of songs a "Playlist" and a group of albums as a "Collection" what would be a good term for a group of musical artists? Would "assemble" be correct?

EDIT: I am looking for what one would call a group of artists placed together, like putting Led Zeppelin, The Doors and Pink Floyd in a grouping titled "Classic Rock Legends".

Comment: I think the word you are looking for is ["ensemble"](https://www.google.com/search?q=ensemble&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=WtJvWO_ICtHZ8gfj8JqgAQ)

Comment: An ensemble would be more of a band made of an assortment of difference musicians rather than just a collective noun.

Comment: Are you asking for musicians that *play together*, or just your list of favorite artists?  The musicians that are signed to a record label (or actors to a movie studio) can be called "a stable".

Comment: If they play together, then "ensemble" would work. If you are looking for a word meaning a group of musicians signed to a label, then "stable", as @JohnFeltz mentioned, works. Could you please provide proper context?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking....

Comment: Perhaps "coterie" would work.

Comment: I added some detail to what I am looking for. Basically a grouping of musical artists  by some shared attribute for reporting purposes.

Comment: In his book, *The Exaltation of Larks*, James Lipton suggests: *a melody of harpists*, *a meter of percussionists*, *a flatulence of bassoonists* and *a backache of double-bassists* - if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having seen your edit, I think you want 'genre' or 'style'.

> Led Zeppelin? I've never heard of them. What style/genre of music do they play?

[Genre](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/genre) (MW, definition 1)

> a category of artistic, musical, or literary composition characterized by a particular style, form, or content

Answer (score 0):

A company or group of actors, dancers, or other performers is called a "troupe"

This is the definition as per freedictionary.com
http://www.thefreedictionary.com/troupe

Comment: [especially one that _travels_](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/troupe)

Comment: Better to add a link to the relevant dictionary as it is available online.

Comment: Have edited my answer to add the link as suggested. Thank you.